# IIS 6, Wildcard Application Mapping, and FrontPage

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic, frontpage

While I'd love to get rid of requiring FrontPage Extensions on a heavy traffic site I host, the client requires it to administrate the site. Having just implemented Wildcard Application Mapping in IIS 6 on this site in order to provide integrated Forms Authentication security between ASP and ASP.NET resources, this breaks FrontPage extensions. Everything works like a charm, including encrypting and caching roles that are now available even to ASP, except for the loss of FrontPage. Specifically, you cannot even login to FrontPage administration (incorrect credentials).

Has anyone gotten FrontPage to work with Wildcard Application Mapping routing through the ASP.NET 2.0 aspnet_isapi.dll?

UPDATE: I've marked @Chris Hynes answer even though I have not had the time to test (and the current configuration is working for the client). It makes sense and goes along with what I thought was occurring and possibly how to deal with, but did not know where to route the request at that point (fpadmdll.dll). Much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here sounds like the wildcard mapping is taking precedence over the frontpage extensions ISAPI handler and/or messing up the request/response for that. I'd try creating a handler that does nothing and mapping it to fpadmdll.dll.

Something like this:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    public IgnoreRequestHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public IsReusable { get { return true; } }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        { }
    }
}
```

Then map it up in the web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add verb="*" path="fpadmdll.dll" type="YourNamespace.IgnoreRequestHandler, YourDll"  />
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this then take the wildcard page requests and pass them to the fpadmdll as well?

All wildcards get the HttpRequest passed to them.  So the FPE request would just get passed to this one as well as the aspnet_ISAPI

Comment: Its getting passed to the ASP.NET handler because it's a wildcard, yes. My thinking is that whatever is in place for the ASP.NET isn't realizing its a fpadmdll request and maybe 404ing it or something before it gets to frontpage. This mapping would keep ASP.NET from touching the request.